# Parsing tab delim file with python with multi header/ large file

Tags: python

Im trying to parse in a large tab delim file with a lot of headers but all methods I've seen on here either take too long or crash / dont work.

Ive tried

```
df = pd.read_csv(path,sep='\t',lineterminator='\r')
```

took too long, and

```
import csv
sterm_list= []
with open(path) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter="\t")
    for x in reader:
        sterm_list.append(dict(x))
```

but got error saying ' dict is not subscriptable'[image]

Comment: Please don't cite your error, but post a full exception with traceback.

Answer (score 0):

easiest way to solve ended up being to manually parse each columns and manually ignore the header columns

```
def parse_water_download(path):
    n_list=[]
    list1, list2, list3, list4, list5, list6 = [], [], [], [], [] ,[] 
    with open(path) as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter="\t")
        for x in reader:
            if x[0][0] != '#':
                if x[0][0]!= '5':
                    USGSagency_cd =x[0]
                    site_no = x[1]
                    datetime = x[2][:10]
                    tz_cd = x[3]
                    var = x[4]
                    var_cd = x[5]
                    list1.append(USGSagency_cd)
                    list2.append(site_no)
                    list3.append(datetime)
                    list4.append(tz_cd)
                    list5.append(var)
                    list6.append(var_cd)
    dict_df = {'USGSagency_cd': list1, 'site_no' :list2, 'datetime' :list3, 'tz_cd': list4, 'var': list5, 'var_cd': list6 }
    
    return pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_df )
```